# EWS C# property LastModifiedTime time not updated after read or unread message

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am doing search for mails using a specific date. I use an or filter with the parameters DateTimeCreated, DateTimeReceived and lastModifiedTime. I also search for a specific property.

The search query is working for messages received or modified (i.e. moved to other folder) after the specific date.

I noticed that messages created before the specific date and changed to read or unread after the specific date are not being retrieved. I expected that messages changed to read or unread had the lastModifiedTime property changed. Below the 
code I am using:

```
    List<SearchFilter> SearchFilterOrColletion = new List<SearchFilter>();
    SearchFilterOrColletion.Add(new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeCreated, UTCfromDate));
                            SearchFilterOrColletion.Add(new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, UTCfromDate));
                            SearchFilterOrColletion.Add(new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.LastModifiedTime, UTCfromDate));
                            SearchFilter SearchOrFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or, SearchFilterOrColletion.ToArray());
    List<SearchFilter> SearchAndFilter = new List<SearchFilter>();
    SearchAndFilter.Add(SearchOrFilter);
    SearchAndFilter.Add(SearchFilterXprProperty);
    SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection FinalSearchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, SearchAndFilter.ToArray());
```

Is there a way to get the time the message was set to read or unread ? 
i.e:

```
1 - Message A received 3:30 pm
2 - Message B received 4:00 pm
3 - Message A read 4:10  pm
Using my search with the time 3:50pm is returning only the message B. I was expecting the message A would be found too (due to the lastModifiedTime) property.
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Adding some info: I observed that using Outlook the LastModifiedTime property is being changed when I set the mail to read or unread. Using OWA of Office 365 it is not happening. To me looks like a bug in OWA.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a bug updating the Read status of a Message doesn't change Last Modified time (this has always been the case in exchange), the one exception is when you reply or forward a message this will modify the PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED property which will then update the Last Modified time.

If you want to track when a Message is read you need to use http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/01/13/exchange-2010-delivery-reports.aspx or you can use EWS Notification and subscribe to the OnRead notification

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thank you for the info. I am already using EWS Notification. It is working properly. My concern is the situation were the EWSNotification is not available. I would like to get the the read status of a specific time frame that I am not receiving the notification.